# Layout-sw320dp is always selected

Tags: android, android-layout

To support multi screen size devices, I created two layout folders for my xml: layout-sw320dp and layout sw480dp folder in layout folder. Then I tested my xml in Nexus S (4 inch) emulator, Galaxy S3 (4.8 inch) emulator, and Galaxy S7 (5.1 inch) actual device. But for some reason, the xml version in layout-sw320dp version is always selected. I browsed the internet, and it seems I should consider additionally density also. If so, how I can do this?

Comment: the qualifier `sw` should be based on the smallest size (either width or height) of the screen, I think `480dp` would be the smallest size for a tablet, not a phone. It sounds like you need `w320dp` instead of `sw`

Comment: If you need separate lyouts for those 3 very similar sizes, you're probably not implementing your UI correctly.

Comment: In my xml, I used extensively, margins and width and heights with fixed dp. That is why, my xml needs to be rendered correctly for these multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

You wrote that you created your folders `layout-sw320dp` and `layout_sw480dp` **inside** of the normal `layout` folder.

They should all be on the same level `src/main/res` instead of inside the `layout` folder.